# Одновременный запуск файлов python в cmd

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Я написал двух ботов для телеграмм.
По отдельности работают хорошо.
Но очень надо чтобы их можно было запустить одновременно.
Если в cmd прописываю:
python bot1.py & python bot2.py - работает только bot1
python bot2.py & python bot1.py - работает только bot2
Можете ли что то посоветовать (новичок в программировании)

Comment: `start python bot1.py & python bot2.py`

Answer (score 0):

Амперсанд выполняет команды последовательно, а не одновременно, т.е это аналогично последовательному запуску двух файлов. Но так как бот работает по - факту бесконечно, то вторая команда для запуска просто не запускается. Я предлагаю следующее, самое простое как по мне решение. Например так:

```
import os
import threading

threading.Thread(target=os.system, args=("python bot1.py")).start()

threading.Thread(target=os.system, args=("python bot2.py")).start()
```

Т.е в двух разных потоках мы запускаем ботов.

Comment: Если не путаю, `&` — это не просто последовательный запуск, а ещё и запуск второго процесса только если первый завершился без ошибки.

Comment: Кстати да, верно подметили